# iOS Increase volume of each sound played

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I am using `AVAudioSession` and `AVAudioPlayer` calling the steps below in my code. However, the sound is not playing on my specified number.

Here is the code:

```
[playSoundURL1 play];
[playSoundURL1 setVolume:(0.5)];
```

Comment: Are you testing it in real device or in simulator?

Comment: I am testing on real device

Comment: Have you test it with maximum volume?